# karto installation

Tags: slam, navigation, ubuntu, ubuntu-lucid, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all!

I'm on a Ubuntu lucid lynx with a ROS Fuerte trying to install slam_karto.

In order to do that, im followind the related tutorial:

http://www.ros.org/wiki/karto

I've already checkouted the code from

https://code.ros.org/svn/ros-pkg/stacks/slam_karto/tags/slam_karto-0.4.0

And im following the steps,

i go to the checkouted folder, create a 'build' folder and excecute the cmake "Unix Makefiles" .. from this recently created folder. It generates a lot of stuff in the build folder, but when i execute make it does nothing at all.

Ok, i go to the karto folder, try with a same recipe (wondering if the folder is not the checkouted but other, cause is not specified in the tutorial), and it not works.

Then i tried with a rosmake in the karto folder (slam_karto/karto/$ rosmake) cause i realized theres a manifest.xml in there. It checkout the karto from svn (i dont know which revision or from where cause is not logged) into a karto-svn folder inner my karto/build folder. and then in the karto-svn folder i find a libOpenKarto.so, but i dont know what todo with that. And in other hand, the samples are not compiled.

Probably i'm missing something obvious, but i use about 4 hours and i didnt find any clue.

Do any one know what could be?

[Here is tree output of my directory.](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/1754431/tree.txt)

Thanks in advice!

PS: this karto folder is in a folder which is registered in ROS_PACKAGE environment variable.

---

Ok, i've solve this after a few more hours.

Here's the trick to make the tutorials.

First at all, despite the url given by the tutorial, you want to checkout the code from this url

https://code.ros.org/svn/karto

Next step, go to the 'source' folder in the checkouted folder.

```
cd [path]/source
mkdir build
cd build
cmake "Unix Makefiles" ..
make
```

The output of this make will generate a libOpenKarto.a, probably without execution privs, so, lets fix that:

```
chmod +x libOpenKarto.a
```

Move this file to /usr/lib in order to be findable by the -lOpenKarto compilation flag
You must be a sudoer to do this.

```
sudo mv libOpenKarto.a /usr/lib
```

now, go to the samples folder

```
cd ../../samples

mkdir build
cd build
cmake "Unix Makefiles" ..
make
```

The output of this process should be the executables of the tutorials, but in order to compile the Tutorial2.cpp you'll need to resolve some dependencies (that i dont resolve yet, when i get that info i'll update this article), just like the README.txt say to.

Now you can just execute the Karto_Tutorial1 and get the spected output

```
./Karto_Tutorial1
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/46329/karto-installation/) by [sbragagnolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3205/sbragagnolo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 203 on 2012-10-19

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've answer my own question in the same space. Hope you find it usefull.

---

Originally posted by [sbragagnolo](https://answers.ros.org/users/3205/sbragagnolo/) with karma: 203 on 2012-10-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2